# remove synonym words from text using nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

so this might be a bit of an amateur question but is there a way to remove synonym words from a text (or a list for that matter) using nltk?
by synonym I also mean same words written differently like :
70's and 70s and 70_s
or dog and hound
I would really appreciate some general guide lines or pointing me to a tutorial (which I could not find any).
thanks in advance

Comment: 1 - To get synonyms, use wordnet.synsets to get sets of synonyms. 2 - To get same words written differently, cleanse the data (remove punctuation and stem. When you stem, run and running will both be converted to run)

Comment: I'll try that. thanks

Comment: In your question, you have two very different and unrelated tasks; Are you also trying to normalize "last Sunday" and "4/23/2017" being the same date? It would greatly help if you stated what are you trying to achieve.
Also, regarding @lordingtar answer, be warned that a word can be in multiple Wordnet sysnsets, even after you have identified it's part-of-speech, for example, check the noun "pen" (this problem is called word sense disambiguation).

Comment: @JosepValls thanks for your reply. basically I have a list of tags and a number assigned to each tag. some of these tags are basically the same or written with different spellings. i need to find the words which are similar in both of these two cases. my biggest problem is I can't find any documentations that describes the methods and classes properly.
my tags don't contain dates or numbers so just finding out the words with similar meaning would suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to delete duplicate items using `wordnet.synsets` to get the synonyms and then just iterated through the list to remove duplicates. I'm sure there are more sophisticated methods than iterating through the list but it worked just fine for me.